# Блок-схема цикла. Теория

Tags: циклы, любой-язык, блок-схема

Я на дистанте прохожу тестрование по циклам, по условию задачи, я должен написать утилиту имея на руках только блок-схему приведённую ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Третий и пятый блок называются верхние и нижние границы условия. Так же, в курсе приводится описание этой блок-схемы. Но и она сбивает меня с толку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если эта блок-схема означает условие "if", то ведь у "if" есть своё собственное обозначение, так же как у "while", "do while" и остальных. Я проваливаю все вопросы, которые связаны с этой блок-схемой.
Спасибо за ответ, Любитель.
Akina, даже если я реализую самый простой Loop в C# типа:

```
static int SumDoWhile()
{
    //
    // Sum numbers 0 .. 4
    //
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
    sum += i;
    i++;
    } while (i < 5);
    return sum;
}
```

То блок-схема к ней будет иметь вид:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

cassini, правильно ли я тебя понимаю, что рисунок самой первой блок-схемы можно описать так:

```
public delegate void TopMessage(string message);
    class Program
    {

       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 0;
            int b = 1;
            do
            {
                b = b + a;
                a++;
            }
            while (a < 5);
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

и это будет правильно?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Конечно существует :) Но в любом случае, цикли в том виде, в котором я их понимаю, должны иметь какое-то конкретное условие. Можно конечно, создать цикл в цикле и так далее, но суть в том, что эти два символа для меня стали открытием, никогда раньше их не встречал. И как я уже сказал, пояснение к этой блок схеме задало мне только больше вопросов.

Comment: Ну вообще-то если первое ещё хоть как-то похоже на цикл, то второе - неприкрытый DO - LOOP.

Comment: Код правильный, да.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это действительно совершенно обычные циклы с предусловием (while) или постусловием (do .. while). Пожалуй основание обратиться к авторам курса.

Несколько источников:

- [Википедия: блок-схема](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0),
- [ГОСТ на блок-схемы](http://cert.obninsk.ru/gost/282/282.html),
- [блог-пост с примером для пузырьковой сортировки](https://pro-prof.com/archives/1462).